# Error 401 when trying to download a file after using Google Picker API

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, authorization, google-picker

I have a react app that allows user to pipe in a particular Google Doc that we then analyze the content of. For step 1, picking the document, I'm using [this nifty npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-picker), which also returns to me an "OAuth token", which I presume to be an `access_token` I can use to make API calls. I set the returned token and the data returned by the Picker API as state variables in my component, as seen below

```
<GooglePicker clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
  developerKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}
  scope={SCOPES}
  onAuthenticate={(token: any) => {
    setGoogleToken(token)
  }}
  onChange={(data: any) => {
    setGoogleData(data);
    nextOnboardingStage();
  }}
  onAuthFailed={(data: any) => console.log('on auth failed:', data)}
  multiselect={true}
  navHidden={true}
  authImmediate={false}
  mimeTypes={['application/vnd.google-apps.document']}
  viewId={'DOCS'}>
  <MyCustomButton />
</GooglePicker>
```

I then try to call the [Drive API export function](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) to download said file in this function

```
const downloadGoogleDoc = async (authToken: string, fileID: string) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileID}/export`, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `token ${authToken}`
    }
  });
  console.log(res);
};
```

However, I'm getting a 401 error when doing this. Can someone point out where I'm losing the auth? Thanks so much

---

Edit My entire component is below

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'];

const Project: React.FC<ProjectInput> = () => {
  const [googleToken, setGoogleToken] = useState<string>();
  const [googleData, setGoogleData] = useState<any>({});

  const [documentData, setDocumentData] = useState();

  const downloadGoogleDoc = async (authToken: string, fileID: string) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileID}/export`, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }
      });
      console.log(res);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  };

  console.log(googleToken);
  console.log(googleData);

  const MyCustomButton = () => {
    return (
      <button className="mx-8 my-2 p-2 rounded bg-blue-500 text-white">
        Select From Google Drive
      </button>
    )
  }

  if (googleToken && googleData.docs) {
    downloadGoogleDoc(googleToken, googleData.docs[0].id);
  }

  return (
    <div className={`ml-${sideBarWidth}`}>
        <FadeIn>
          <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-gray-500 py-6 justify-center sm:py-12">
            <div className="py-3 sm:max-w-xl sm:mx-auto">
              <div className="bg-white min-w-1xl flex flex-col rounded-xl shadow-lg">
                <div className="flex">
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      <div className="px-8 py-5">
                        <h2 className="text-gray-800 text-3xl font-semibold">Great! Select the document you'd like us to scan</h2>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <GooglePicker clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
                      developerKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}
                      scope={SCOPES}
                      onAuthenticate={(token: any) => {
                        setGoogleToken(token)
                      }}
                      onChange={(data: any) => {
                        setGoogleData(data);
                        nextOnboardingStage();
                      }}
                      onAuthFailed={(data: any) => console.log('on auth failed:', data)}
                      multiselect={true}
                      navHidden={true}
                      authImmediate={false}
                      mimeTypes={['application/vnd.google-apps.document']}
                      viewId={'DOCS'}>
                      <MyCustomButton />
                    </GooglePicker>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </FadeIn>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Project;
```

---

EDIT

As @Tanaike said, I needed to include MimeType in my request, working function is below

```
  const downloadGoogleDoc = async (authToken: string, fileID: string) => {
    try {
      const params = new URLSearchParams([['mimeType', 'text/html']]);
      const res = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileID}/export`, {
        params,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }
      });
      console.log(res);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you provide the code related to where you are calling `downloadGoogleDoc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal and your situation as follows.

- You want to know the reason of the error of `401`.
- From your script, I thought that you might want to download a file which is not Google Docs file (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides and so on).

  - Because when the Google Docs file is downloaded, the endpoint is not correct. When you use the method of "Files: export" in Drive API v3, `mimeType` for exporting is required to be used.
  - But from your replying, I understood that you wanted to download a Google Docs file using the method of "Files: export".
- Your access token can be used for downloading the file from Google Drive.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your following script, I noticed a modification point except for endpoint.

  ```
    const res = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileID}/export`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `token ${authToken}`
      }
    });
  ```

  - In this case, `token` is not correct. Please modify it to `Bearer`. I thought that this is the reason of the error `401`.
- When `catch` is used, the error message can be retrieved.
- If you download a binary file, the binary data is directly retrieved. At that time, when `responseType: 'arrayBuffer'` and `responseType: 'blob'` are used, the data is retrieved as array buffer and blob, respectively.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
const res = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileID}/export`, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `token ${authToken}`
  }
});
```

To:

```
const mimeType = "###"; // Please set the mimeType.
const res = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileID}/export?mimeType=${mimeType}`, {
  // responseType: `arrayBuffer`, // or 'blob'
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err.response));
console.log(res);  // or res.data
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that your access token can be used for downloading the file from Google Drive. So please be careful this.
- When you use the method of "Files: export", please use the Google Docs files as the file ID. Please be careful this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_document)

#### References:

- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Comment: Thank you, I modified the script per your recommendation, but I am now getting a 400 error. Which I think is good news as I'm authenticated, but I must be calling the Drive API incorrectly still

Comment: You were right about needing mimetype, I just needed to use it as a query parameter in my request. I'll edit my question so everyone can see. Please update your answer and I can accept it

Comment: @Alex Chumbley From your replying of `You were right about needing mimetype, I just needed to use it as a query parameter in my request.`, I understood that you wanted to download a Google Docs file using the method of "Files: export". For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?